# MySQL Shortest Path between two nodes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table as defined below:

`SELECT * FROM paths`

```
source | destination
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 4
4 | 5
3 | 5
```

I am trying to find the shortest path between 1 and 5 and not sure what SQL query would get that result. This is what I have right now:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT destination, CAST(destination AS CHAR(200)) AS path
  FROM paths WHERE source = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.destination, CONCAT(cte.path, ",", c.destination)
  FROM paths c JOIN cte ON cte.destination=c.source
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY path;
```

I am not sure how I would limit the query above to only find paths that end at 5. Example of what I am looking for:

All paths between 1 to 5:

- (1 -> 2), (2 -> 4), (4 -> 5)
- (1 -> 3), (3 -> 5)

In this case, the shortest path that I want the query to return is the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not too far away. Just add the paths' lengths in the recursion. Then filter the final result for the destination node and use `ORDER BY` the paths' lengths and `LIMIT` to get only one shortest path (if there are more than one path with the minimum length one of them is chosen randomly).

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte
AS
(
SELECT p.destination,
       concat(p.source, '->', p.destination) path,
       1 length
       FROM paths p
       WHERE p.source = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT p.destination,
       concat(c.path, '->', p.destination) path,
       c.length + 1 length
       FROM cte c
            INNER JOIN paths p
                       ON p.source = c.destination
       WHERE c.destination <> 5
)
SELECT c.path
       FROM cte c
       WHERE c.destination = 5
       ORDER BY c.length
       LIMIT 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdc1834edb67be7fc2670fff85408faa)

One thing you might consider though is loop handling, if there can be loops in the graph. Unless node 5 is in such a loop you'd have an endless recursion.